# Parameters in pyodbc in pandas read_sql_query

Tags: pandas, pyodbc

Given the following query string,

```
symbol = "'AAPL'"

query = """SELECT TOP (1000000) 
       [date]
      ,[symbol]
      ,[open]
      ,[high]
      ,[low]
      ,[close]
      ,[volume]
      ,[exch]
      FROM [AMEXEOD].[dbo].[Stocks_eod]
      where 
          symbol = :symbol
      order by 
         date desc"""
```

When I try to execute it:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params={'symbol': symbol})
```

I get an error:

```
('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

I thought the `:symbol` is the way to mark parameters?

Comment: Unlike other DB-APIs, pyodbc does not [support named parameters](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/227). Use `?` placemarker instead and pass list into *params* argument of pandas' `read_sql`.

Answer (score 1):

What version of python are you using? As you *should* be able to use string formatting.

Python 2.x

```
symbol = "'AAPL'"

query = """SELECT TOP (1000000) 
       [date]
      ,[symbol]
      ,[open]
      ,[high]
      ,[low]
      ,[close]
      ,[volume]
      ,[exch]
      FROM [AMEXEOD].[dbo].[Stocks_eod]
      where 
          symbol = {0}
      order by 
         date desc""".format(symbol)
```

Python 3.x

```
symbol = "'AAPL'"

query = """SELECT TOP (1000000) 
       [date]
      ,[symbol]
      ,[open]
      ,[high]
      ,[low]
      ,[close]
      ,[volume]
      ,[exch]
      FROM [AMEXEOD].[dbo].[Stocks_eod]
      where 
          symbol = {symbol}
      order by 
         date desc"""
```

Lots of detail [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) on this if you're interested.

Add then use this in your query:
`df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)`

Comment: this query is not parameterized, and therefore subject to sql injection.